# Choice of correct design pattern for spell-casting mechanism

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm new in OOD and I don't really know how to handle the spell-casting mechanism which i want to implement in my game.

- I want to produce following classes`Team`, `Actor`, `Spell` and interface `SpellEffect`
- Actor can cast spells on other actors however the spell **can** have different behaviour while being casted on allies and enemies ( ally is an actor from the same team )

I tried this way:

- I implement `SpellEffect` in `Damaging`, `Stunning`, `Healing` classes which overrides `executeOn(Actor a)`
- In `Spell` class I have two lists of `SpellEffect` - one for allies and second for enemies so in the Spell class I need to know is the attacked actor is and ally or enemy of the caster
- I was thinking about **StrategyPattern** for spell so I can do something like this:

  ```
  actor.setCastingStrategy( new TargetingAllyStrategy() )
  ```
- Strategies would be then something like:

  ```
  execute a spell on the targeted actor using Spells's allyCast() method
  ```

However I'm not sure about passing Actor object to the lower level object. Moreover what if not every actor can be stunned? Should I make any inherited class UnstunnableActor ? Or maybe use instanceOf to check implemented interfaces. I'm pretty new in the topic so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will never have the third class of actors (only allies, enemies) I don't think strategy pattern is needed here.

I think you can make your actors implement either `AllyActorInterface` or `EnemyActorInterface`. And `Spell` will just test what interface actor supports and apply chosen effects by calling `allyCast` or `enemyCast`.

You can also think of splitting Spell class into `EnemySpell` and `AllySpell` if your logic of applying effects differ too much. You can implement a template method to select which class of spells to apply to which actor then.

Comment: Thanks for response! The point is I would like to avoid making allies and enemies. I would like to stay with actors generally. So for the actor1 from teamA the ally would be actor2 from teamA and enemy would be actor3 from teamB.